# Finding a UMP test of $H_0: \lambda \leq 1$ vs. $H_1: \lambda > 1$ for Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Here is what I have so far:

\begin{align}
\Lambda &= \frac{L(\lambda_1)}{L(\lambda_0)} \\[8pt]
&= \frac{\prod \frac{\lambda_1^{x_i}}{x_i!}e^{-\lambda_1}}{\prod \frac{\lambda_0^{x_i}}{x_i!}e^{-\lambda_0}} \\[8pt]
&= \left(\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_0}\right)^{\sum x_i}e^{-n(\lambda_1-\lambda_0)}
\end{align}

We see that the Poisson family has a MLR in $T(X) = \sum x_i$. By Karlin-Rubin theorem, the test with rejection region $C=\{T(X) > t_0\}$ is UMP level $\alpha$  where $t_0$ satisfies $P_{\lambda_0}(T(X) > t_0) = \alpha$. But now I'm stuck.

How do I find an expression for $t_0$ using $P_{\lambda_0}(T(X) > t_0) = \alpha$?

Comment: You know $\alpha$ and you know $\lambda_0,$ and you want to know the smallest value of $t_0$ for which $P_{\lambda_0} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i > t_0 \right) \le \alpha.$ Is that a correct understanding of your question?

Comment: I just want to know an expression for $t_0$ I don't need a value per se

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it lack a closed form. If $n\lambda_0$ is large you can approximate $\operatorname{Poisson}(n\lambda_0)$ by $\operatorname N(n\lambda_0,n\lambda_0)$ and use a continuity correction. $\qquad$

Comment: Following your suggestion I have the following now:

\begin{align}
\alpha &= P_{\lambda_0}\left(\sum x_i > t_0 \right) \\
&=1 - P_{\lambda_0}\left(\sum x_i < t_0 \right) \\
&=1 - P\left(Poisson(n\lambda_0) < t_0 \right) \\
&\approx1 - P\left(N(n\lambda_0,n\lambda_0) < t_0 \right) \\
&\approx1 - P\left(N(0,1) < \frac{t_0-n\lambda_0}{\sqrt{n\lambda_0}} \right) \\
&\rightarrow t_0 \approx n\lambda_0 + Z_{1-\alpha} \sqrt{n\lambda_0}
\end{align}

Let me know if I messed anything up

Comment: However, I don't know what n is so I'm not actually sure if this is right.

Comment: By $n$ I meant the number of terms in the sum. And note that I suggested using a continuity correction.